# How to create rippleview custom like rounded cornner in android and ripple effect apply only in round?

Tags: android, button, rounded-corners, ripple

I am develop an android application in which I need rounded corner ripple button with ripple effect only within rounded corner in android.

Thank's

Comment: `"i need rounded corner ripple button with ripple effect only within rounded corner in android."` it makes no sense at all...

Comment: it is useful, but the ripple view is not rounded corner so how I can make it rounded corner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use one library for ripple effect. im satisfied

https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect/blob/master/README.md